# Accessing value of string literal through `const char *` glvalue in constexpr gives error

Tags: c++, constexpr

I was testing out the capabilities of `constexpr` inc C++. My code is:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

#define LOG(KEY) \
    do { \
        constexpr unsigned key_len = sizeof(#KEY); \
        constexpr const char*const key_val = #KEY; \
        constexpr unsigned key_hash = bernstein_hash(key_val, key_len); \
        printf("%s : %u\n", #KEY, key_hash); \
    } while (0)


constexpr unsigned bernstein_hash (const char* key, const unsigned len)
{
    const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *)key;
    unsigned h = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        h = 33 * h + p[i];

    return h;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LOG(STACKOVERFLOW);

    return 0;
}
```

However I get a compilation error when trying to compile this:

```
accessing value of ‘"STACKOVERFLOW"’ through a ‘const unsigned char’ glvalue in a constant expression
```

I can't understand what the error means. Googling the error also didn't yield any results.

Comment: `const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *)key;` - eeew. Why doesn't the function just take a `const unsigned char*` argument if that's what it needs?  `#define LOG(KEY)` - :-( Why a (evil!) macro rather than a regular function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(const unsigned char *)key` is the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast`. You can't do that in `constexpr` code.

It would be better to just convert the individual `char` values into `unsigned char`:

```
h = 33 * h + static_cast<unsigned char>(key[i]);
```

Particularly in C++20, when a potential signed-to-unsigned conversion is well-defined.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the rationale why `reinterpret_cast` are disallowed in `constexpr`- Is it a restriction because `reinterpret_cast` will have portability issues? But wouldn't `constexpr` in general have portability issues?

Comment: @tinkerbeast: "*Would you mind explaining the rationale why `reinterpret_cast` are disallowed in `constexpr`*" It's kind of beside the point. It's not allowed, and it's not *going* to be allowed anytime soon. Remember: in constexpr code, UB becomes a compile error (*including* strict-aliasing violations), so most uses of `reinterpret_cast` aren't going to work anyway.